# By which program can I change UNICODE filenames in my whole disk to ASCII?

Tags: windows-xp, conversion, unicode, filenames, ascii

By which program can I change UNICODE filenames in my whole disk to ASCII?

Comment: On what OS, using what filesystem?

Comment: i use windows XP, filesystem FAT32 or NTFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Linux, take a look at [Glindra rename](http://www.glindra.org/doc/rename.html), [detox](http://linux.die.net/man/1/detox) and [convmv](http://linux.die.net/man/1/convmv).

Source: [Fixing Unix/Linux/POSIX Filenames: Control Characters (such as Newline), Leading Dashes, and Other Problems](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html)

Glindra is also available for Windows.

Comment: i use windows XP, filesystem FAT32 or NTFS.

Comment: @trante: Glindra works on Windows. Sorry I didn't say that in my answer.